# Custom headers in request with HttpServletRequestWrapper don't appear in client side

Tags: java, http, servlets, header, request

I want add a custom header into Servlet request.

At first, I have built a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` class

```
public class HeaderRequest_DEBUG extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private static final String DEBUG_NAME="Authorization";
    private static final String DEBUG_VALUE="foccalabindella";

    public HeaderRequest_DEBUG(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(HeaderRequest_DEBUG.DEBUG_NAME)){
            return HeaderRequest_DEBUG.DEBUG_VALUE;
        }
        return super.getHeader(name);
    }


    @Override
    public Enumeration getHeaderNames() {
        //create an enumeration of the request headers

        //create a list
        List list = new ArrayList();

        //loop over request headers from wrapped request object
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)getRequest();
        Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            //add the names of the request headers into the list
            String n = (String)e.nextElement();
            list.add(n);
        }

        list.add(HeaderRequest_DEBUG.DEBUG_NAME);

        //create an enumeration from the list and return
        Enumeration en = Collections.enumeration(list);
        return en;
    }

}
```

So, I've built a `Fileter` to wrap the standard request:

```
public class Filter_DEBUG implements Filter{


    @Override public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}
    @Override public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //if the ServletRequest is an instance of HttpServletRequest
        if(servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            //cast the object
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
            //create the FakeHeadersRequest object to wrap the HttpServletRequest
            HeaderRequest_DEBUG request = new HeaderRequest_DEBUG(httpServletRequest);
            //continue on in the filter chain with the FakeHeaderRequest and ServletResponse objects
            filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
        } else {
            //otherwise, continue on in the chain with the ServletRequest and ServletResponse objects
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }      
    }
}
```

At last, I've built a page for test:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Initial page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         header: <%=request.getHeader("Authorization")%>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, with Firefox/Firebug I have this situation: in the browser window I have this message:

```
header: foccalabindella
```

But in Firebug I didn't see that header:

```
GET /myServer/jsp/welcome.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: JSESSIONID=465C24CC9A113E270F72829E35155BBB
Connection: keep-alive
```

To confirm this, if I add a submit button and I read request in a servlet, I haven't that header

Comment: It wasn't put in the response header. The request header does not reach the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it doesn't show up in Firebug. It wasn't the browser who has set that header. It was your own code in the server side who did that **after** having received the request from the browser. Any changes made to that request in the server side in order to fool the remaining of the server side code in the stack that the browser has sent it won't be reflected back in the original request which the browser made. All which the browser retrieves back is the HTTP response. There's no way to change the initial HTTP request from the HTTP response on.

Whatever functional requirement you've in mind for which you thought that this is the right solution needs most likely to be solved differently.

Comment: ok, what is the correct solution to resolve my requirement? something like to build a servlet, add header in `Response` and dispatch my jsp?

Comment: As long as you don't elaborate the functional requirement, it's hard to propose the right solution. I have no utter idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: simple ; ), my jsp has to call a server that needs Authorization key in request header, that's all

Comment: You mean, an external server? Why are you trying to set it in the request to your own server instead of in the request to the external server? Where exactly is the request to the external server? I don't see it in the code provided so far.

Comment: Yes it is. beacause I have a server that provides a jsp witch calls a another (external) server. That external server needs Authentication key in request.